# HD wallet usage in Bitcoin & Lightning combined wallets

Tags: wallet, lightning-network, bip32-hd-wallets

Is there a best practice / recommendation for a Bitcoin & Lightning combined wallet, regarding the HD wallet used in the Bitcoin wallet and the HD wallet used in the Lightning wallet?

- no relation, independent wallets
- use same wallet (e.g with different derivations in Lightning node)